# image popup over navbar links

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the ghost image pop-in and pop-out every time I click on the link for each links.
Now the ghost images are all visible over the links all I want is to click on the link and see the image to show up and disappear after that,for all links.

```
    <nav class="main-navbar">
        <ul class="main-navbar-list">
            <li class="main-navbar-link">
                <a href="#" class="main-navbar-item">link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-navbar-link">
                <a href="#" class="main-navbar-item">link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-navbar-link">
                <a href="#" class="main-navbar-item">link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-navbar-link">
                <a href="#" class="main-navbar-item">link 4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-navbar-link">
                <a href="#" class="main-navbar-item">link 5</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-navbar-link">
                <a href="#" class="main-navbar-item">link 6</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>




    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 3px 6px;

}

.main-navbar-list {
    display: flex;
    width: 55%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.main-navbar-link {
    position: relative;
}

.main-navbar-item::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: -60%;
    left: 10%;
    background-image: url("https://icons8.com/preloaders/preloaders/1479/Ghost.gif");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 50%;
    height: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render a background image on nav links, you can use:
li:active, li:focus

```css
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 3px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 3px 6px;

}

.main-navbar-list {
    display: flex;
    width: 55%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.main-navbar-link {
    position: relative;
}

.main-navbar-item::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: -60%;
    left: 10%;
   /* background-image: url("https://icons8.com/preloaders/preloaders/1479/Ghost.gif");*/
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/*right here, UPDATED 3-14-2022*/
   li:hover{
   background-image: url("https://icons8.com/preloaders/preloaders/1479/Ghost.gif");
}
```

```html
    <nav class="main-navbar">
        <ul class="main-navbar-list">
            <li class="main-navbar-link" ><a href="#" class="main-navbar-item"> link 1</a></li>
            <li class="main-navbar-link">
                <a href="#" class="main-navbar-item">link 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-navbar-link">
                <a href="#" class="main-navbar-item">link 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-navbar-link">
                <a href="#" class="main-navbar-item">link 4</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-navbar-link">
                <a href="#" class="main-navbar-item">link 5</a>
            </li>
            <li class="main-navbar-link">
                <a href="#" class="main-navbar-item">link 6</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but this solve part of my problem unfortunately.
Now the image appears when I click on the link.
I would like to have the image to popup behind the link when I hover it.
How can I achieve that please?

Comment: To implement this, you will need to swap out and use li: hover. I have updated the snippet in my answer.

Comment: thank you for your help.
I have learned something new today.
I don't really think you are a Junior BTW,lol.